# Filling out the form fields in docx using golang library unioffice

Tags: go, office365

I'm trying to fill out the form fields using unioffice library. The document that i'm working with, contains several paragraphs. The paragraphs contains several form fields.
I want to fill out all of the form fields in the document. And here is the code i'm running:

```
    doc, err := document.Open("form.docx")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening form: %s", err)
    }

    for i := range doc.FormFields() {
        doc.FormFields()[i].SetValue("test")
    }

    doc.SaveToFile("filled-form.docx")
```

However, not all of the form fields were filled out.

Comment: Can you give an example word file? Additionally, use `for _,file:= range doc.FormFields()` instead of `i`

Comment: @sHartmann, here is the file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/668493hp1yrbv8t/form.docx?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a bug in `func (d *Document) Save(w io.Writer) error{}`. I can read and write to every of the `FormFields` but only the last `FormField` value in the paragraph gets actually saved to the file.

Below code works like expected until you save to file. (That means it prints out the previously set value). I saw you already opened a new issue on github ([link](https://github.com/unidoc/unioffice/issues/305)) i hope you have more luck with that.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/unidoc/unioffice/document"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    _, err := ioutil.ReadFile("filled-form.docx")
    if err == nil {
        err = os.Remove("filled-form.docx")
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }

    doc, err := document.Open("form.docx")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening form: %s", err)
    }

    for _, f := range doc.FormFields() {
        if f.Type() == document.FormFieldType(1) {
            f.SetValue("test")
        }
    }

    for _, f := range doc.FormFields() {
        log.Println("-------------------")
        log.Println(f.Name())
        log.Println(f.Value())
    }

    err = doc.SaveToFile("filled-form.docx")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```